# Extracting unique consecutive values from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file that contains the following information

[image]

and I need to extract that data into a dataframe with unique values from column ID and value 1; so that I will end up with something like this:

[image]

I have done the following:

```
df=pd.read_excel(file)
dfUnique=pd.unique(df[["column ID","value1"]]).values.ravel('K')
```

but I get the following error:

> could not broadcast input array from shape (5,2) into shape (5)

Comment: `df.groupby(['column ID','value1']).first()` or `df.groupby(['column ID','value1']).head()`

Comment: thank you sir, it worked

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['column ID', 'value1'])`.